# My reaction collector for Discord.js v13 starts collecting but doesn't actually collect

Tags: node.js, discord.js

The purpose of this little code is to change the message to the name of the emote that was used in the users reaction to the base message. This works in discord.js v12... I am just completely stuck as to why this won't work in v13. The collector does send the proper end message when it stops collecting (if I put it on a timer) but any code I put inside the listener just doesn't execute upon reaction. I have tested with console.log and such. Any help is very much appreciated! (I do have all the proper intents enabled.)

```
client.on("message", (message) => {
 if (message.content.toLowerCase() === prefix + "reaction") {
    message.channel.send("react to this").then(m => {
    // I know the filter here is not useful but it's for the future
      const filter = (reaction, user) => {
        return true
      }
      const collector = message.createReactionCollector({ filter }); //edited form m to filter
      collector.on("collect", (r) => {
        m.edit(r.emoji.name)
      })
      collector.on("end", (collected) => {
        m.edit("reaction listening stopped.")
      })
    })
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your createReactionCollector has issue, it should be:

```
const collector = m.createReactionCollector({ filter });
```

Comment: lol such a silly mistake thank you works very well